# angular sibling components change detection

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular2-changedetection

see this stackblitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-knjzvr

clicking the button, which is in the hello component, triggers an update in the goodbye component, causing the getData() call there to execute. and twice, even...

check console for output.

could someone explain this behavior ?

the real-world case is different (an observable in a service updates on an interval, triggering not only the affected component to be triggered, but the whole app), but this simple case seems to be the same.

Comment: Might Englighten you : https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html

Comment: thanks, good article. however, even if change detection is triggered, I don't really understand why the template is re-evaluated in the other component, especially since no change has occurred in that other component.

I'll try playing with some of the change detection option to see where that gets me.

Comment: 1. The change detection is triggered when click event is dispatched.
2. Change detection is uni-directional, i.e. from top to bottom due to which it starts from the root of zone and detect for changes. By Default angular app is under on zone due to which complete app detect for changes.